# Canon 80D with Canon GP-E2 add log data to CR2

Tags: canon, raw, geotagging

I have searched high and low and cannot find a solution to this problem. I have a Canon 80D with the GP-E2 GPS module. When attached to the camera it records the GPS data of a photo taken in the CR2 file. There is an option to keep it off camera in logging mode and using the now defunct Canon Map Utility you should be able to add the data from the GP-E2 logs to the photos. Support ended for this app in 2019 and it doesn't seem to work for me. Lightroom will only create sidecar files from the log data and will not embed it in the CR2 files.

Sure, I can have the unit on the camera for every shot and do what I want but I would like to have it off camera and logging and add the data to the CR2 files later not as sidecar files. I know the compass data will not port over which is fine but the location data is important to me.

I have see people using exif tool to do this with all kinds of hacks and such, I am trying to find a simple reliable way to append the log data to the photos without a ton of effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (which I use) is to:

1. Convert Canon GP-E2 GPS log from NMEA-0183 to GPX with GPSBabel
2. Then load the RAW files in [geotag software](http://geotag.sourceforge.net/). As this is java software you can run it on almost any OS.
3. Then load the track in geotag software.
4. Right click on any image->Find location->for all images (for example)
5. Optionally  Right clink on any image->Location names->for all images
   **in File->settings I will recommend to select General settings->Always write to XMP settings** Otherwise the software will create backup copy of RAW files and incorporate location information in RAW files. But I personally prefer not to touch the original files on any way.
6. File->Save new locations->for all images

Comment: If you go the GPX way  you can just as well use a trip recorder in your smartphone.

Comment: @xenoid, correct. I use on Android pretty good software (which consume negligible amount of energy, for 12 hours < 10%)

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks! Let me give this a try and if it works I will accept your answer. I am going to test the first option. I really want to avoid sidecar files unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I installed Java but it only allows me to keep downloading the JRE and installing Java over and over again. Windows 10 x64

Comment: @Cyberdrew, maybe you should ask question here https://superuser.com/ about this problem with java.

Comment: @Cyberdrew, about sidecar files: I personally prefer not to touch RAW files, because specs of RAW files are not publicly available and I am not sure how much the developer will preserve the original files.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution that seems to work for me for now.

Using the CR2 files and the actual NEMA Log Files from the GP-E2 I am able to geotag the photos using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/geotag.html). It opens in Lightroom, Abobe Camera Raw and Google photos fine with the location marked.

I place my photos and the log file from the GP-E2 in the same directory then run the following command in a command prompt pointed to that directory:

> exiftool -geotag=C:\Temp\track.log C:\Temp\

**Testing Results:**

This is with the GP-E2 attached to the camera:

[image: With GP-E2 attached to the camera]

This is a side by side of the file with no gps data and after running the exiftool geotag switch:

[image: This is a side by side of the file with no gps data and after running the exiftool geotag switch]

Answer (score 0):

I do this in Lightroom using GPX files from a phone.  In the Library panel select all the photos you want to tag.  If it is all of the ones you are working on ctrl-A or command-A will do this.  Go to the Map panel, load the tracklog and select Autotag photos.  If you don't want to touch the original RAW files, copy them before reading into Lightroom.

Comment: Lightroom will not change the CR2 (Raw) files even if I wanted it to. It only creates sidecar files.